# I have other system in sub-folder, how to write .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I have a PHP system A(the .htaccess as follow) and I need to put other system B sub-folder under A's just like htp://www.a.com/B/
how to change the code to make this work? (just because right now when I type htp://www.a.com/b/  can see login page, but when I login , will redirect to htp://www.a.com/index.php )

## thanks!!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} rewrite
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule index\.php(.*) $1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^$ "/index.php?rewrite" [qsa,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(js|css|jpe?g|jpe|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

multiple rewrites
RewriteRule /?(.*) "/index.php?rewrite=$1" [qsa,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just below `RewriteBase` insert this `RewriteRule` to skip a directory `B`:

```
RewriteRule ^B(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]
```